# How to integrate infusionsoft-php-sdk in cakephp3

Tags: cakephp-3.0, infusionsoft

I want to create a contact in infusionsoft from cakephp code, I have put infusionsoft sdk inside vender folder and call include file in my controller but it giving error when creating object of infusionsoft.

Comment: This is almost certainly a [namespace](http://php.net/manual/en/language.namespaces.php) issue. That should help you Google solutions. Also, if you read up on composer autoloading, perhaps starting with the CakePHP section on [Autoloading Plugin Classes](https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/plugins.html#autoloading-plugin-classes), you may find that you don't even need to include the file, if other things are set up correctly.

Comment: Thanks for suggestion but I have already tried namespace.

Answer (score 0):

I have resolved error myself by simply write use classname;

Classname is which object we want to create in controller.